# Android IR Remote Override Power Key

Tags: android, android-hardware-keyboard

How to Override the power key of an IR remote for a rooted Android device? I have tried the following

```
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_STB_POWER:
            Toast.makeText(this, "KEYCODE_STB_POWER key pressed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_AVR_POWER:
            Toast.makeText(this, "KEYCODE_AVR_POWER key pressed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TV_POWER:
            Toast.makeText(this, "KEYCODE_AVR_POWER key pressed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER:
            Toast.makeText(this, "KEYCODE_POWER key pressed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
```

But none of the above worked. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try logging the key so you get the actual KeyEvent to be treated.
for example:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d("keycode", "" + keyCode);
(...)
}
```